# how to get sqlite query works on mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, match

I have sqlite query
I want to get it works on mysql database 
I used MATCH AND AGAINST but it does not help if you see this part

```
'TEST:^hello '
```

How can I do that?
thanks

```
SELECT * FROM table_a MATCH 'TEST:^hello ' AND test2 = 'hello'
```

I using MATCH , AGAINST now in my MySql query and I want to find all the words who start with "hello " (you seeing the space after hello!)
so how can I do that using FULLTEXT search with MATCH AND AGAINST?

```
words
hello
hello how are you
you are good hello
hello ?
nice hello fine

I want this 
hello
hello ?
hello how are you
nice hello fine 
you are good hello
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland can you give me example to mysql query to find 'TEST:^hello '

Comment: @Anna you want to get all the records where test matches `hello` and test2 is hello right?

Comment: topicstarter should provide a example and expected results then we can stop guessing..

Comment: in MySQL the best bet is most likely using `MATCH(column)  AGAINST('+hello ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND column REGEXP  '^hello '`

Comment: thank you, edited my question

Comment: *"thank you, edited my question"* i posted a answer about the regex suggestion did you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I using MATCH , AGAINST now in my MySql query and I want to find all
>   the words who start with "hello " (you seeing the space after hello!)
>   so how can I do that using FULLTEXT search with MATCH AND AGAINST?

As `MATCH() AGAINST()` in MySQL does not support `REGEX`, I most likely would go for.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
   *
  FROM
   test
  WHERE
   MATCH(word) AGAINST('+hello ')      
) AS fulltext_scan
WHERE 
 fulltext_scan.word REGEXP '^hello '
```

Or

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

  SELECT 
   *
  FROM
   test
  WHERE
   MATCH(word) AGAINST('+hello ')

) AS fulltext_scan
WHERE 
 fulltext_scan.word LIKE 'hello %'
```

The way this works the inner sql (delivered table) limits the result based on `MATCH(word) AGAINST('+hello ')` and can use a [FULLTEXT index](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rZ5gajgqPqb4VnfCoTGNai/2) to speed it up. 
The outer SQL filters that resultset with a REGEX or with LIKE to match only the hello starting.

Comment: its working thanks but when I search for swedish word I got this ```1139 Got error 'nothing to repeat at offset 1' from regexp``` word with ä,ö,å

Comment: @Anna yea only MySQL 8.0 i believe has good utf8 regex support, under MySQL 8 regex only really works on latin1.